# How to save pdf file generated in spring mvc in to database directly after being generated..?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, itext

This is my class for generating a pdf. It generates a pdf when I submit the form, but I could not figure out how to save it to the database.

```
public class BookingPdf {

        private static String FILE = "D:/Hotels/pdf/";
        protected static Font font10;
        protected static Font font10b;
        protected static Font font12;
        protected static Font font12b;
        protected static Font font14;

        public static String generateBookingPDF(Booking booking) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            String bookingname = booking.getFirstName() + " " + booking.getLastName();
            document.addHeader("HOTEL SWING", "Hotel Swing Booking confirmation");
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE + "Booking" + " " + booking.getCustomer().getFirstName() + ".pdf "));
            writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOC);
            writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
            document.open();
            String html = htmlTemplate(booking);

            List unorderedList = new List(List.UNORDERED);
            unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Name       :" + booking.getFirstName() + " " + booking.getLastName()));
            unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Room  :" + booking.getRoom().getRoomNumber()));
            unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Total Price  :" + booking.getTotalPrice()));
            unorderedList.add(new ListItem("check in   :" + booking.getRoom().getRoomNumber()));
            unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Booking:" + booking.getbId()));

            document.add(unorderedList);
            document.close();
            return bookingname;

        }

        private static String htmlTemplate(Booking booking) {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            html.append("" + "<h1> Booking Confirmation</h1>  ");
            return html.toString();

        }

        public BookingPdf(Booking booking) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public BookingPdf() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
```

here is my controller class from where I want to save the pdf location and save it to the database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("Booking") Booking booking, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException, ParseException, DocumentException, IOException {
        Customer customer = customerService.getById(booking.getCustomer().getC_id());
        Room room = roomService.getById(booking.getRoom().getRo_id());
        long totalNights = (booking.getCheckoutDate().getTime() - booking.getCheckinDate().getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        System.out.println(totalNights);
        booking.setTotalNights((int) totalNights);
        int totalPrice = (booking.getTotalNights() *  booking.getRoom().getRoomPrice());
        booking.setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
        System.out.println(totalPrice);
        System.out.println("check" + booking);

        try {
            booking.setCustomer(customer);
            booking.setRoom(room);
            if (booking.getbId() == 0) {
                bookingService.insert(booking);
                BookingPdf.generateBookingPDF(booking);

            } else 
               {
                bookingService.update(booking);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
        return "redirect:";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BLOB dataType, converting the file in byte[] array.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: I did but I got  HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter &#39;file&#39; is not present I am trying to generate and upload in to database at same time

Comment: Are you using form with type  "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: I hope this link is udefull for you  https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file to your server and then save the directory path in the database. So when the user needs to redownload it you have a separate controller for downloading pdfs generated in the past.

Another option is to use a library such as [Jasper](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library), where you can define a template, and when the report needs to be generated/downloaded you pass in the relevant parameters.

Comment: I have saved the file into specific location after it  is generated I am having problem to store the generated file location in to database so that if the user with particular id can download it ..Bookingpdf class works perfectly while save the form it generates but I don know how to set the location in to database .

Comment: I can see you're storing your pdf in `D:/Hotels/pdf/`, but I don't see anything indicating that this value is being saved to your database anywhere. It should just be a case of taking the file's directory and its name and writing some code to save that to a table with a reference so that the user can download it later on.

Comment: that is what I am trying to do if you don mind can you help me with the code must not be specific as an example relevant to my question I am totally new to spring mvc ..